# App engine Datastore Implementation

Tags: date, google-app-engine, time, google-cloud-datastore

I'm making a system in appengine and can't find the correct way to implement this in the datastore. I could do so in a normal relational databases but just can't get my head around this.

In the datastore is an entity, this entity has a "close" and "open" time for each day.

This is all easy so far BUT: Occasionally there could be 2 + "open" and "close" times in one day.

Can anyone offer some advice on the correct implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not specify if you are working in Java, Python or Go, I'll give you a Python example, but the general concept can be implemented in either.

Python has NDB API (newer than DB API) that includes a "repeated" property flag: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#repeated

When you make a property repeated, "The property takes a list of values of the underlying type, rather than a single value. ", so this way you can specify multiple open and close times.

When you retrieve the info for the specific day, you can then loop through the list to see if the time you are processing this falls between one of the open/close windows. If one open/close is found, break the loop and process the request.

One thing I would strongly recommend, is to keep track of pairs of open/close and eliminate any overlap with validation. This will make your processing easier.

Comment: You can do the same thing in the "old" db using ListProperty. NDB is just nicer but they both work in exactly the same way: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses

Answer (score 1):

You can create a model that keeps each pair of open-close dates, lets name it `WorkingPeriod`. Then, in your main entity either you can have either a list of embedded `WorkingPeriod` values or a list of `Key` that point to the `WorkingPeriod` entities. It depends on which approach best fits your needs.

Hope this helps!